# What is the Latin term "pace" used for when referencing other scholars?

Tags: citations, etiquette, writing, writing-style, terminology

I frequently come across references to other scholars like:

> In period P, syntactic construct C did not have function F (*pace* Smith 2000).

I understand that *pace* here signals that Smith (2000) suggests that C *did* have function F in P (see [this related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/43593/18875) for the basic meaning of *pace*). But I'm having trouble relating this to the literal meaning of *pace* ('in peace'). Does the above mean:

1. That the author holds Smith in high regard (suggested [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/71010/18875), but this seems odd to me since the relationship between the author and Smith is irrelevant to the content).
2. That no offence to Smith is intended (suggested [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/47157/18875), but this also seems odd in an academic work: Smith is aware of the scientific method and the fact that his claims may be challenged).
3. That the author acknowledges that there are currently different opinions on the matter and that the author accepts Smith's point of view because the matter cannot be settled with the evidence currently available?
4. Something else?

I am looking at a dissertation here where the author at times rebukes another scholar quite strongly, without *pace*, ("the analysis of Smith is a step backwards from the 100 year old description by Jones"), but at other times uses *pace* to describe a difference of opinion more neutrally ("*pace* Smith who does not differentiate further here"). This suggests to me that *pace* signals something about the content of the referenced proposition rather than the author's attitude to the referenced scholar.

It's just unclear to me what *pace* signifies exactly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I checked with the author and he explained it as similar to option 3: He used it to indicate that he respects the arguments cited by Smith, while he gives more weight to other evidence leading to different conclusions. Since it is in part subjective to what evidence is given more weight, both positions are respected.

However, I can imagine that some authors simply use *pace* for variation from *contrary to* without this particular nuance. (As may be clear from my question, this was in the field of linguistics and written by an author with an exceptional sensitivity to the finer nuances of language.)